# Redirect to view in other image folders using ImagePicker plugin in android (Ionic 3)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-plugins

I am using the image picker plugin in my Ionic app. I want able to pick images from other folders from the gallery in android device. For Ios it is possible but for android I am getting this view. [image]

But I want user able to go to other folders and select images from it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I supose you are using cordova plugin `File`. If you want select others routes, u can use the diferents directories provided by `File`. EJ:

```
this.file.applicationStorageDirectory
this.file.applicationDirectory
this.file.documentsDirectory
```

You have the complete list here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

If you need more help, say to me.

to use  if With Filepicker use a constant to set options:

```
const options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  customButtons: [{ name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook' }],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};
```

and send it to the picker:

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
```

Comment: actually, I am using [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/image-picker)  `Image Picker` plugin. I dont want to use cordova plugin `File`

Comment: Hi Ragesh, Is there any option for this. I am also want the same feature.